# Same custom column name in 2 different solutions, 2 different ID guids, yet I get a "Duplicate field 'x' was found" error

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, solution-package, site-column, duplicate

So I have two completely different solutions, I'll call them solutionA.wsp and solutionB.wsp and they are being deployed to the same site

Both of them contain a site column definition for a column named "WorkOrder"

Here's the definition found in solutionA.wsp

```
      <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Work Order" Description="Order Number" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Decimals="0" Group="Custom Group A" ID="{BBBD31AD-8D18-4BD3-AFCD-5F6249328B2F}" StaticName="WorkOrder" Name="WorkOrder" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
```

and here's the column, as I defined it in solutionB.wsp:

```
      <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Work Order" Description="Order Number" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Decimals="0" Group="Custom Group B" ID="{AABD31AD-8D18-4BD3-AFCD-5F6249328B2c}" StaticName="WorkOrder" Name="WorkOrder" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
```

On a clean development SharePoint site instance, I've successfully deployed both .wsp files, but, I can only activate the features of one or the other, but not both.

I thought the difference in GUID's between the two columns was enough to prevent this error from occuring.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StaticName` and `Name` also have to be unique between the columns.

Comment: I was just figuring this out as I browsed my site structure via SharePoint Manager. I had taken for granted that the duplicate field names I saw listed in it's treeview were coming from the Name field, when in fact, it was merely the DisplayName that was duplicated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The display names can be same but the internal names have to be unique for each column.